# Subset of data frame base on the value in column or neighboring columns

Tags: r

I would like to find which column contains the highest number of `1`. Number `1` should appear only once per row. As soon as column with highest number `1` will be located the script should check also neighboring columns (`+1+` / `-1`) and if any of them contain number `1` it should be also selected. All of these rows should be kept within subset function.

Let's put part of original data:

```
structure(list(   `10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  `34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `59` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),  `84` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                 `110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `134` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                 `165` = c(0, 0, 0, 0), `199` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                 `234` = c(0, 0, 0, 0),
                 `257` = c(0.0160178986200301, 0, 0.0409772658686249, 0.0289710439505515),
                 `362` = c(0.0679054515644214, 0.126933274414494, 0.0855598028367368, 0.0596214721268868),
                 `433` = c(0.490914059297718, 0.604765061128296, 0.813348757670254, 1),
                 `506` = c(1, 1, 1, 0.971410482822965),
                 `581` = c(0.198244295668807, 0.234158197083517, 0.269655970224324, 0.195318383259472),
                 `652` = c(0.271177756524115, 0.223018854028576, 0.301352982597324, 0.142584385725234),
                 `733` = c(0.212426561005602, 0.212778023272942, 0.228513228045468, 0),
                 `818` = c(0.213816778248395, 0.168570481661511, 0.264465345538678, 0),
                 `896` = c(0.137102063123377, 0, 0.320234382858867, 0),
                 `972` = c(0.108932231179123, 0, 0.179106729705261, 0),
                `1039` = c(0.101762535865555, 0, 0, 0),
                   EOD = c("Peter", "Peter", "Peter", "Peter"),
               Complex = c(""FT team", "FT team", "FT team", "FT team")),
          .Names = c("10", "34", "59", "84", "110", "134", "165", "199",
                     "234", "257", "362", "433", "506", "581", "652", "733",
                     "818", "896", "972", "1039", "EOD", "Complex"),
          row.names = c("Peter_1_Rep_1_E", "Peter_1_Rep_2_E",
                        "Peter_1_Rep_3_E", "Peter_1_Rep_4_E"),
          class = "data.frame")
```

As you can clearly see in the original data the column `506` should be selected as the one containing the highest number of `1` and data should be subseted base on it. However, output would be exactly the same because in this data neighboring fraction (-1, `433`) contains also `1`. That's easy example.

Situation might be more complicated, like in that case:

```
structure(list(    `10` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                   `34` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                   `59` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                   `84` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `110` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `134` = c(0.168783347110543, 0, 0.382618775924215, 0, 0.530638724516877, 0, 0.169526042048202, 0),
                  `165` = c(1, 0.36380544964196, 1, 0.13979454361738, 1, 0.239652477288689, 1, 0.240341578327444),
                  `199` = c(0.355158938904336, 1, 0.646724265971128, 1, 0.582637073151552, 1, 0.20319390520841, 1),
                  `234` = c(0.0963628165627114, 0.575436312346942, 0.229853828180188, 0.433555069046817, 0.247567185011894, 0.508529485059242, 0.138356164383562, 0.389880251276011),
                  `257` = c(0, 0.17393595585728, 0, 0.127787133715056, 0, 0.117147323350173, 0, 0),
                  `362` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0919333108790839, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `433` = c(0, 0, 0, 0.0745570899292691, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `506` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `581` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `652` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `733` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `818` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `896` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                  `972` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                 `1039` = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0),
                    EOD = c("Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul", "Paul"),
                Complex = c("GG Team", "GG Team", "GG Team", "GG Team", "GG Team", "GG Team", "GG Team", "GG Team")),
          .Names = c("10", "34", "59", "84", "110", "134", "165", "199", "234", "257", "362", "433", "506", "581", "652", "733", "818", "896", "972", "1039", "EOD", "Complex"),
          row.names = c("PaulG_1_Rep_1_E", "Paul_1_Rep_1_E", "PaulN_1_Rep_2_E", "PaulG_1_Rep_2_E", "Paul_1_Rep_3_E", "PaulC_1_Rep_3_E", "PaulC_1_Rep_4_E", "Paul_1_Rep_4_E"),
          class = "data.frame")
```

In that situation there are two columns which contain the same number of `1s`. In this case column with bigger `colsum` should be selected.

Comment: your data contains no row with more than one `1`. You can check this using `rowSums(d == 1)`

Comment: Sorry, I wrote it incorrectly. Data is fine. When it locates the column with highest number of `1s` it should look if neighboring fractions from this one contains `1` in any other row than the ones which has been already selected.

Comment: I edited the whole question. Please take a look on updated version.

Comment: please edit you question and include your expected output and the rows you wanted to be filtered out.

Comment: Done. Just notice please that I am looking as well at column `qsec` (-1) but in this case it does not contain any `1`.

Comment: is this what you want? `d[rowSums(d > 0) > 9,]`

Comment: Can you elaborate what this function do ? I will try with my original data but it looks too simple :)

Comment: Can you give an example of what output you expect to see?  I think the solution is very simple, but I don't understand what you're asking, even after cleaning up the formating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

let `df1` be your input:

```
df_num <- df1[,sapply(df1,is.numeric)]            # keep only numeric columns to build filter
n1 <- colSums(df_num == 1)                        # number of 1s per column
i  <- which(n1 == max(n1))                        # index of cols with max 1s
if(length(i) > 1){
  max_cs <- which.max(colSums(df_num[,i]))        # index of col with max colsum among results
  i <- i[max_cs]                                  # our column index
}
filter <- rowSums(df_num[,seq(max(i-1,0),min(i+1,ncol(df_num)))]==1) >0    # filter is true if chosen column is 1 or if any neighbour is 1

df1[filter,] # your result
```

In both of your examples, all rows are kept

Comment: That looks fine until it reaches problem when the highest number of `1` is identified in first or last column. It tries to check neighboring columns but on one side there is nothing. `Error in rowSums(data[, seq(j - 1, j + 1)] == 1) : 
  error in evaluating the argument 'x' in selecting a method for function 'rowSums': Error in `[.data.frame`(data, , seq(j - 1, j + 1)) : 
  undefined columns selected`

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the tidyverse to convert it to long format then pull in the column sums to determine where the first one (with the largest sum) is:

```
library(tidyverse)

# add rownames to the data frame
df2$id  <- rownames(df2)

# make a data frame of each column's sum
thecolsums  <- colSums(df2[,map_lgl(df2, is.numeric)]) %>% 
  enframe(name = "colname", value = "colsum")

# change the data frame to long format
dflong  <- df2 %>% 
  mutate(rowid = row_number()) %>% 
  gather(colname, val, -rowid)

# which column has the first 1 value
whichcol  <- dflong %>% 
  group_by(colname) %>% 
  filter(val ==1) %>% 
  summarize(
    firstone = min(rowid, na.rm = T)
  ) %>% 
  left_join(thecolsums, by = 'colname') %>% 
  filter(colsum == max(colsum)) %>% 
  pluck('colname')

# what's the numerical index of the column
whichcolindex  <- which(names(df2) == whichcol)

# get previous and next columns if they exist
prevcolindex  <- ifelse(whichcolindex < 1, F, whichcolindex -1)
nextcolindex  <- ifelse(whichcolindex == ncol(df2) , F, whichcolindex +1)

# do the previous and next columns have 1s in them?
prevcolhasone  <- any(df2[,prevcolindex] == 1)
nextcolhasone  <- any(df2[,nextcolindex] == 1)

# create a vector with 1, 2 or 3 column indexes
finalindex  <- c(
    prevcolindex[prevcolhasone]
  , whichcolindex
  , nextcolindex[nextcolhasone]
)

# subset the original data frame, only preserving the columns in question
results  <- df2[, finalindex]
```